# Android Compose LazyColumn real-time UI changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The value was changed in real time through rememberSaveable in one of several views in LazyColumn, but other views also changed as well.

```kotlin
fun Post(
    postData: PostData, viewModel: PostViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val icCommentImagePainter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_comment)
    val postGoodCounts = rememberSaveable { mutableLongStateOf(postData.goodCounts) }
    val goodStatus = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(postData.goodStatus ?: false) }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.postGoodState.collect {
            if (it.isSuccess) {
                goodStatus.value = it.goodStatus ?: false
                postGoodCounts.longValue = it.goodCounts
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 30.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
    items(postData) {
        Column {
            Post(postData = it)
            HorizontalDivider(
                color = CustomColor.Gray,
                thickness = 1.dp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [`hiltViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/hilt/navigation/compose/package-summary#hiltViewModel(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,kotlin.String)) documentation:

> Returns an existing HiltViewModel-annotated ViewModel or creates a new one **scoped to the current navigation graph** present on the {@link NavController} back stack.

You have the following code in your Post Composable:

```
viewModel: PostViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

This will return the **same ViewModel instance** for **every single** `Post` Composable, as all of them are in the same destination in your `NavGraph`. If you update a field in the ViewModel from one `Post`, then all other `Post`s will have the same change.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think about that.